# Replaced a gem by its git repo, nothing works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

I used the gem enumerated_attribute; however, the gem is not up to date and for last version I must use the git repo.

So I changed my gemfile as follows:

```
#gem 'enumerated_attribute'
gem "edave-enumerated_attribute", :git => "https://github.com/edave/enumerated_attribute.git"
```

After that I ran `bundle install` which removed the gem and copied the repo.

Now the rail apps react as if enumerated is not installed:

```
undefined method `enum_attr' for #<Class:0xa90d1c0>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered this exact issue.  I found that I could not update to a forked version of a gem, having already installed the original gem.  Using bundler, the new version is picked up properly, but the changes are not reflected in Rails.

The following command should resolve the problem:

```
rails plugin install https://github.com/edave/enumerated_attribute.git --force
```

I would also suggest doing the following, just to ensure you have the expected gem version in your local repository (outside of your Rails app):

1. Uninstall the gem using `gem uninstall <gem_name>`
2. Check out a copy of the source for the forked gem you wish to use
3. Build the gem from source:  `gem build <gem_name.gemspec>`
4. Install the gem to your local repo: `sudo gem install <gem_name-version.gem>`

I found the details for these steps here: [Installing a Gem Fork from GitHub Source](http://raflabs.com/blogs/silence-is-foo/2010/07/19/installing-a-gem-fork-from-github-source/).